# Android - Add buttons to stock camera

Tags: java, android

I currently have an app that has a `Share Via` button on images, I was wondering if it's possible to maybe somehow add a button to the camera itself that allow to take a picture and pass it to my activity?

I know I can make an activity which takes an image from within my activity and then get the image, but I was wondering if there's a way to add it to the stock camera.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that Google would not allow that, but you can register for pictures shared from the gallery.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? what does it mean?

Comment: more explanations below. AFAIK thats the only possibility you will get.

Comment: Not possible, think about the stock camera as another apk, unless you decompile it, hack it and install it again, which again ain't possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can only register to the share intent from the gallery:

```
<intent-filter ...>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

This will allow your users to take pictures, than share to your app from the gallery (not from camera app)

For obvious reasons, you cannot add a button for your app only in stock camera app.